# how to select directory to save the output?

Tags: html, electron

How select folder save our output file using html css and javascript.
we can select the input file using input type = file, how to select the directory where we wanna save the output file.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't unless you use the new file system API where you can only save to where the original file was selected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't possible in a typical web browser context, but since you tagged this [electron](/questions/tagged/electron), you can use [the `dialog` API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog) from Electron remote:

```
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;

const directory = dialog.showOpenDialogSync({
    properties: ['openDirectory'],
});
```

Comment: Thanks thanks for your message that works, right I'm doing this from java script from webview, can you please tell me that how to make communication between webview and main window(main.js)

Comment: "webview"? "main window"? Do you mean renderer and main process? https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer

Comment: yean, I'm loading html page through electron-tabs and that uses webview the embed the page, so how can I make communication between javascript in embedded page and main process?

Comment: Isn't it possible to write to a directory from a browser context using the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API)?